# How to make my app stay on top of fullscreen apps

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, osx-lion

I have an app which must always stay on top of other applications.
I'm currently using the setLevel property for the main window to keep it on top of other desktop applications.

I'm trying to fix my app so it can also stay on top of full-screen apps in Lion. 
Any ideas on how this can be done?

The Application delegate looks like this:

```
#import "alwaysOnTopAppDelegate.h"

@implementation alwaysOnTopAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [window setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];
}

@end
```

Comment: Since the whole point of full screen mode is to focus on one application to the exclusion of all others, I would have thought the behaviour you are trying to implement would be considered undesirable by most full screen app users and it might even be impossible to implement.

Comment: The behavior would of course be optional. There is a "Staff favorite" app in the app store which has this feature: http://itunes.apple.com/dk/app/yoink/id457622435?mt=12

Comment: I stand corrected, clearly, it's not impossible to implement and even has Apple's approval in the right circumstances.

Comment: Perhaps change NSFloatingWindowLevel to NSScreensaverWindowLevel? That should put it in front of literally every single thing except the mouse.

Comment: NSScreenSaverWindowLevel did not do the job :(

Comment: hey petur, did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes.
`- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [window setLevel:kCGMainMenuWindowLevel-1];
    [window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorStationary|NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces|NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary];
}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer: The app delegate should look like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [window setLevel:kCGMainMenuWindowLevel-1];
    [window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorStationary|NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces|NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The way that Yoink works is simple:
Just set "Application is Agent (UIElement)" to YES in the Info.plist for your application. It will mean it doesn't show in the dock etc. but that's probably fine for an auxiliary window (well, it was for me!). It probably makes sense to provide a menu bar item in this case so the user can stop the application easily.

Comment: That does not keep it on top of fullscreen apps in lion.

Answer (score 0):

follow is my test code, it work ok, hope can help.

```
NSPanel *test_panel = [[NSPanel alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(300, 300, 500, 500) styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
[test_panel setReleasedWhenClosed:YES];
[test_panel setHidesOnDeactivate:NO];
[test_panel setFloatingPanel:YES];
[test_panel setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask | NSNonactivatingPanelMask];
[test_panel setLevel:kCGMainMenuWindowLevel-1];
[test_panel  setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces|NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary];
[test_panel setCanBeVisibleOnAllSpaces:YES];
[test_panel center];
[test_panel orderFront:nil];
```